# Display frontend errors in popup modal

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, uicomponent, frontend-error, modal-popup

If there's a problem on the checkout, the error is displayed near the top, for 5 seconds and then it goes away. Most customers don't even see the message.

Often, on smaller devices, the message isn't seen by the customer and they will continue to repeat the action, regardless of the message.

I have managed to get the error to display longer than 5 seconds, but a better method would be displaying the error in a pop-up modal that would display even on mobile devices.

However, I can not seem to find a way to be able to display customer frontend errors inside a modal that would require an action to close.

*Is there a module than allows the front end error message to be displayed in a popup modal?*

If anyone has an idea on how to make this happen, please let me know. I think it would go long way into helping the customer complete the order, rather than abandoning the cart, because they didn't see the error.

Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms for this, but I had a hard time imagining I'm the only one having this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this free module `https://www.mageants.com/custom-message-extension-for-magento-2.html`

I didn't install it and check but as per there the screenshot, I think its fit in your requirements, just check this maybe solve your problem.

Comment: I could never get the demo to work, but the user guide shows that it takes over the formatting on all messages and doesn't create a modal, but a location, which may be troublesome on mobile devices. Where I really only need the error display is on the checkout. Most people don't even see the error and continue to click away.